# How to use Mathematica for demonstration of analysis of Boolean functions?

Tags: fourier-analysis, boolean-computation, demonstrations

I am wondering how to use Mathematica to demonstrate some concepts in [Analysis of Boolean functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_Boolean_functions), e.g.:

- Influence
- Noise stability
- Noise operator
- $L_q$-norm and $L_\infty$ norm of a boolean function

Any help would be appreciated.

---

All $2^{(2^2)}=16$ boolean functions $f: \{ -1,1 \}^2\rightarrow \{ -1, 1\}$ are:

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 -1 \\
 \frac{x_2 x_1}{2}+\frac{x_1}{2}+\frac{x_2}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \\
 -\frac{1}{2} x_2 x_1+\frac{x_1}{2}-\frac{x_2}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \\
 x_1 \\
 -\frac{1}{2} x_2 x_1-\frac{x_1}{2}+\frac{x_2}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \\
 x_2 \\
 -x_1 x_2 \\
 -\frac{1}{2} x_2 x_1+\frac{x_1}{2}+\frac{x_2}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{x_2 x_1}{2}-\frac{x_1}{2}-\frac{x_2}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \\
 x_1 x_2 \\
 -x_2 \\
 \frac{x_2 x_1}{2}+\frac{x_1}{2}-\frac{x_2}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \\
 -x_1 \\
 \frac{x_2 x_1}{2}-\frac{x_1}{2}+\frac{x_2}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \\
 -\frac{1}{2} x_2 x_1-\frac{x_1}{2}-\frac{x_2}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Answer (score 2):

I don't find that, so I implemented some concepts by myself.

Any supplementation would be appreciated.

---

#### The number of boolean functions whose Fourier degree is exactly $d$ and inputBinaryWord length is $n$.

Here the Fourier degree of a boolean function $f:\{ -1,1 \}^n \rightarrow \{ -1,1 \}$ is its degree as a multilinear polynomial.

```
n = 2;
inputWords = Tuples[{-1, 1}, n];
outputResults = Tuples[{-1, 1}, 2^n];
expr = {Product[1/2 (1 + Subscript[a, i] Subscript[x, i]), {i, n}]}~
   Join~Array[{Subscript[a, #], {-1, 1}} &, n];
allIndicatorFunctions = Flatten[Table @@ expr];
allBooleanFunctions = 
  Table[Expand[fa . allIndicatorFunctions], {fa, outputResults}];
allBooleanFunctions // TableForm
polynomialDegree[expr_] := 
  Max[0, Max[Total@*First /@ CoefficientRules[expr]]];
(polynomialDegree /@ allBooleanFunctions) // Tally
```

The number of boolean functions $\{ -1, 1\}^{n} \rightarrow \{-1, 1 \}$ whose Fourier degree **equals** to $d$:

$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccccccccc}
n\backslash d  & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8  \\ \hline
1 & 2 & 2 & - & - & - & - & - & - & -  \\
2 & 2 & 4 & 10 & - & - & - & - & - & -  \\
3 & 2 & 6 & 62 & 186  & - & - & - & - & - \\
4 & 2 & 8 & 212 & 12648 & 52666 & - & - & - & - \\
\cdots & - & - & - & -  & - & - & - & - & - 
\end{array}
$$

The diagonal elements are the diagonal elements in the array are sequence [A037267](https://oeis.org/A037267).

#### The $i$'th influence of a boolean function

$$
\operatorname{Inf}_i [f]=\mathrm{E}[(\frac{f-f^{\oplus i}}{2})^2]=\sum_{S \ni i} \hat{f}(S)^2
$$

Where $f^{\oplus i}$ denotes the output obtained by flipping the $i $-th bit of the input vector.

```
iThInfluenceOfFunctionf[original_, bitsNumber_, ithBit_] := 
 Module[{iThBitFlipped, expr}, 
  iThBitFlipped = 
   original /. {Subscript[x, ithBit] -> -Subscript[x, ithBit]};
  expr = {((original - iThBitFlipped)/2)^2}~Join~
    Array[{Subscript[x, #], {-1, 1}} &, bitsNumber];
  Table @@ (expr) // Flatten // Mean]

Table[iThInfluenceOfFunctionf[booleanFunction, n, 
    ithBit], {booleanFunction, allBooleanFunctions}, {ithBit, n}] // 
  Flatten // Tally
```

#### Total influence of $f$, namely, the average sensitivity

$$
\operatorname{Inf}[f]=\sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Inf}_i[f]=\sum_S|S| \hat{f}(S)^2
$$

The sensitivity of a boolean function $f$ at a given point is the number of coordinates $i$ such that if we flip the $i$'th coordinate, the value of the function changes. The average value of this quantity is exactly the total influence.

```
totalInfluenceOfFunctionf[f_, bitsNumber_] := 
  Sum[iThInfluenceOfFunctionf[f, bitsNumber, ithBit], {ithBit, 
    bitsNumber}];
totalInfluenceOfFunctionf[#, n] & /@ allBooleanFunctions
```

#### $\rho-$stable influence of a boolean function

$$
\operatorname{Stab}_\rho[f]=\mathrm{E}_{x ; y \sim N_\rho(x)}[f(x) f(y)]=\sum_{S \subseteq[n]} \rho^{|S|} \hat{f}(S)^2
$$

```
noiseStabilityOfFunctionf[f_, \[Rho]_] := 
 CoefficientRules[f] // 
   Map[(\[Rho]^Total[#[[1]]])*(#[[2]])^2 &, #] & // Total
noiseStabilityOfFunctionf[#, \[Rho]] & /@ allBooleanFunctions
```

#### The noise sensitivity of $f$ at $0\leq \delta\leq 1$

$$
\operatorname{NS}_{\delta}[f]=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Stab}_{1-2\delta}[f]
$$

If $f$ is boolean, then this is the probability that the value of $f$ changes if we flip each coordinate with probability $\delta$, independently.

```
noiseSensitivityOfFuncitonf[f_, \[Delta]_ ] := 
 1/2 - 1/2*noiseStabilityOfFunctionf[f, 1 - 2 \[Delta]] // Expand
noiseSensitivityOfFuncitonf[#, \[Delta]] & /@ allBooleanFunctions
```

#### $L_q-$norm of a boolean function

$$
\|f\|_q=\sqrt[q]{\mathrm{E}\left[|f|^q\right]} .
$$

```
LqNormOfFunctionf[f_, bitsNumber_, q_] := Module[{expr},
   expr = {Abs[f]^q}~Join~
     Array[{Subscript[x, #], {-1, 1}} &, bitsNumber];
   Table @@ expr // Flatten // Mean // (#^(1/q)) &];

Table[LqNormOfFunctionf[f, n, 2], {f, allBooleanFunctions}]
```

#### $L_{\infty}-$norm of a boolean function

$$
\|f\|_{\infty}=\max _{x \in\{-1,1\}^n}|f(x)| .
$$

```
LInfinityNormOfFunctionf[f_, bitsNumber_] := 
 Module[{expr}, 
  expr = {Abs[f]}~Join~Array[{Subscript[x, #], {-1, 1}} &, bitsNumber];
  Max[Flatten[Table @@ expr]]]
LInfinityNormOfFunctionf[#, n] & /@ allBooleanFunctions
```